# Wrong constructor name in Angular/TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an component in Angular:

```
export class StudentsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
}
```

In another component I tried to display name of class `StudentsComponent` preliminarily imported `StudentsComponent`:

```
console.log(StudentsComponent.constructor.name);
```

Why it gives me in console `Function` instead `StudentsComponent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StudentsComponent` *is* a constructor. It itself is constructed by the `Function` constructor. Use `StudentsComponent.name`.

Comment: Always to get class name to use `.name`?

Comment: @OPV a [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) is just a [`function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) that can only be [constructed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new). All functions have a [`name` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name).